# How to associate a Windows program to open a file based on extension AND CONTENT?

Tags: windows, file-management, file-association, xml

Is there a way to associate a Windows program to open a file based not only on extension, but also on its **content**?

### Reasonable use case

Many programs use the `XML` format to store their files. I'd like to associate several different programs with the XML extension, based on the content of the file.

The discriminator is usually at the very beginning of the XML file, such as

```
<mxfile .... editor="www.draw.io" type="github">
```

or

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" ...>
```

I can imagine a solution like:

1. A single application "Universal File Opener" is associated with the `XML` extension in Windows, or other extensions shared among multiple applications. However, for now I have a use case only for `XML`
2. Based on a regular expression match (or something like that), the program choses the proper owner application of the file and launches it.

**Is there anything like this?** Or anything else to reach the same goal?

There is an older question [Windows file association based on file type and then size](https://superuser.com/q/921488/282786), the accepted solution is similar to what I am suggesting, but I'd like to re-use if there is anything more generic already written, rather than elaborating with writing batch files.

Comment: You could associate it to powershell, and make a script to decide which application to open based on the file's contents ... I don't know if this is possible with registry only (it might be)
Edit: You'd have to associate it to powershell SCRIPT, not powershell.exe. I think it could be done

Comment: @hextech That's exactly what I wanted to avoid - writing a script :) I was wandering if there might be something already available.